# can't install request module for python 3.4 windows

Tags: python, pip

i made a 2 python  programs for trying cx
_freeze
first program(name:example.py):

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aura_Kingdom'
values = {'s':'basics',
          'submit':'search'}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('utf-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
respData = resp.read()


paragraphs = re.findall(r'<p>(.*?)</p>',str(respData))
for eachP in paragraphs:
    print(eachP)
```

2nd program(name: setup.py):

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(anme = 'urlparse',
      version='0.1',
      description='Parse stuff',
      executable = [Executable("distme.py")])
```

---

succesfully installed cx_freeze. tried to build setup.py using command py setup.py build it gives error: in line 1 import urllib.request ImportError: No module named request.tried installing request module using pip install request but it gives error: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\user\jalaj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-e7xz36j3\request

Comment: By chance could it be saying _requests_? Those are two different modules. Try running `pip install requests` and see if that helps.

Comment: tried pip install requests too it installed successfully but when tried setup.py build it still showed the same error no module named request